# My result in my jQuery gives NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting `NaN` as result and its beacuse my jquery is multiplying numbers that look like `"204,3 * 3"`

How can I deal with it?

I cant change the price, so what can I do?

`"234 * 2"` works fine as soon as the number have `','` I get `NaN`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.quantity').keyup(function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent(),
            price = parent.find('.price').html(),
            quantity = parent.find('.quantity').val(),
            result = price * quantity;
        parent.find('.price2').html(result);
    });
</script>

     <span class="price">69,9</span>
     <input type="text" class="quantity">    
     <span class="price2">69,9</span>
     <span class="total">Total:</span>
     <div class="line2"></div>
```

[Check my JSfiddle everything is there](http://jsfiddle.net/pFzgf/9/)

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Feel free to post the code here. Questions should be self-contained, we don't want to rely on outside websites being available forever to keep questions on SO useful.

Comment: Use `204.3` instead.  Also, it is generally best to convert stuff to floats, if that is how you intend to use them.

Comment: Javascript has trouble with commas. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205730/javascript-parsefloat-500-000-returns-500-when-i-need-500000

Answer (score 4):

Javascript uses North American number formatting, which means the `,` is used as a `thousands seperator` and the `.` is used `decimal separator`.

You have two solutions to your problem:

- Teach your users to enter numbers like `1000.25`
- Write a routine to turn `1.000,25` into `1000.25`

`String.prototype.replace` would be your friend on the second choice.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to multiply strings...use the parseFloat() and a replace() method as shown in your jsFiddle update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pFzgf/15/)

```
 $('.quantity').keyup(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent(),
        price = parent.find('.price').html().replace(',', '.'),
        quantity = parent.find('.quantity').val().replace(',','.'),
        result = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(quantity);
    parent.find('.price2').html(result);
});
```

Comment: How is using parseInt() going to help with fractional numbers?!

Comment: oh sorry, parseFloat()? Updated code and fiddle to show changes

Comment: sometimes it gives like " 207,700000000007

Comment: yeah, you'll have to insert a number format routine for that, it only does the calculation

Answer (score 1):

You are **multiplying two strings** here and not numbers..

Convert them using **parseInt  with radix**

OR

Convert them using **parseFloat**

Change this line

```
 result = price * quantity;
```

**TO**

```
result = parseInt(price,10) * parseInt(quantity,10);
```

OR

```
result = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(quantity);
```

Comment: @AlianaRose -- Double check your math and make sure you are getting the results that you expect.  The `parseFloat()` method will **strip** the `,3` from your input.  `parseFloat("10,3") === 10`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Oh I didnt notice that, damn :( Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: @AlianaRose -- See both my answer and the link that Laurence left as a comment.  Mine explains what is happening and why, the link gives some solutions.