# How to convert this string containing a number with comma into floating equivalent?

Tags: javascript

I have this string containing a number with a comma that is like this `"9,848.48"`. I want to convert it to its floating equivalent which is `9848.48`. I tried using `parseFloat()` but the result I got is `9`. How can this be done in javascript?

Comment: *"PS: please do not downvote as I am at risk of being blocked..."* That sort of thing is counter-productive. If you've asked so many questions that have been downvoted, **your** behavior needs to change, not the behavior of the community. In this case, for instance, just read the documentation of the `parseFloat` fucntion, which is perfectly clear. If you don't like [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3) (it **is** really hard to read), there's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: And/or search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205730/javascript-parsefloat-500-000-returns-500-when-i-need-500000

Comment: Certainly not suggesting to change the behavior of the community. I believe the downvotes are my fault. Unfortunately, some members of the community downvote without telling me why even if the reason is legitimate. I cannot change my behavior if I do not know why. Not everyone is as kind as you, Sir.

Comment: The [help] has quite a large amount of guidance on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all commas from the string before calling parseFloat:

```
val = val.replace(',', '');
var parsed = parseFloat(val);
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `,` and convert it to float using `parseFloat`

```
parseFloat("9,848.48".replace(',', ''));
// 9848.48
```

Answer (score 1):

`var number="9,848.48";
number=number.replace(/\,/g,''); 
number=parseInt(number);`
remove the comma then parse to int

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove commas from the string, try this:

```
parseFloat('9,848.48'.replace(',', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace method in javascript to replace "," with "".

After that you do your necessary parsing.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the comma before calling `parseFloat`