# Unable to remove comma on a number (JS, HTML)

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I'm working on an electron app HTML based and I'm stuck with a js code that separates numbers with a comma.

On my app, I get the number: 4,344.064
I want to remove and disable the "," as 4344.064

Here, this number is the number of tokens (erc20) held on an ethereum address and when I try to send a transaction with a web3 call (token from my address to another address), I'm only able to send up to 4 token so my app counts only the number before the ",".

I can send 1, 2, 3 or 4 tokens but when I try from 5 I can't so I'm sure that the problem come from the comma.

I've tried a lot of change on my js file but I'm unable to locate this function without removing the ".".

JS CODE :

```
function updateBalance() {
var address = myWallet.address;
$(".myaddress").html(address);

provider.getBalance(address).then(function(balance) {
    var etherString = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
    console.log("ETH Balance: " + etherString);
    var n = parseFloat(etherString);
    var ethValue = n.toLocaleString(
        undefined, // use a string like 'en-US' to override browser 
 locale
        {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }
    );
    var messageEl = $('#ethbal');
    var split = ethValue.split(".");
    ethBalance = parseFloat(ethValue);
    messageEl.html(split[0] + ".<small>" + split[1] + "</small>");
});

var callPromise = tokenContract.functions.balanceOf(address);

callPromise.then(function(result) {
    var trueBal = result[0].toString(10);
    var messageEl = $('#tokenbalance');
    var n = trueBal * 0.00000001;
    console.log("Token Balance: " + n);
    var atyxValue = n.toLocaleString(
        undefined, // use a string like 'en-US' to override browser 
locale
        {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }
    );

    var split = atyxValue.split(".");
    tokenBalance = parseFloat(atyxValue);
    $(".neurealspend").html(atyxValue)
    messageEl.html(split[0] + ".<small>" + split[1] + "</small>");

});

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Could you please provide a working example? So we can help you better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript parseFloat '500,000' returns 500 when I need 500000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205730/javascript-parsefloat-500-000-returns-500-when-i-need-500000)

Answer (score 1):

This is "By Design". The parseFloat function will only consider the parts of the string up until in reaches a non +, -, number, exponent or decimal point. Once it sees the comma it stops looking and only considers the (in "4,344.064" only "4") portion.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat
To fix this convert the commas to decimal points.

refer - [Javascript parse float is ignoring the decimals after my comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma)

How ever there is a workaround,
I would suggest to go like the below,

```js
   //source - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma/22453862

console.log(parseFloat(("43,434,344.064").replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, "")))
```

Comment: This leaves you with '4.344.064' which parseFloat turns into 4344 which loses the numbers after the decimal.  It would be better to remove the commas altogether.  If it was a larger number like '4,354,343' it would get parsed down to 4354 and completely loses the value.

Comment: updated code to handle such scenario, can you please check @Alex L Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: n = "4,354,343.90"; console.log(parseFloat((n).replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, ""))) - you need to pass "n" to the parseFloat method instead of "Token Balance:"

Comment: Im now good with   tokenBalance = parseFloat(atyxValue.replace(/,/g,''));  thanks very much !

Comment: you are welcome! thanks for giving opportunity to help you :) @0x44N

Comment: sorry @0x44N i have not worked on electron, but please try on me, will help you to find solution :)

Comment: are you getting any error on the console? please share

Comment: let me check give me few min

Comment: can you please read this page, you need to run --asar with config again, read this  https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/issues/35